# Зачем нам синицы с журавлями

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Всем известна поговорка "Лучше синица в руках, чем журавль в небе". Но, если задуматься, образы очень странные. Зачем мне нужна синица? Не есть же ее?
Почему бы для этой оппозиции не выбрать другие образы:

"Лучше копейка в руках, чем рубль в трактире" или
"Лучше коза в сарае, чем корова в лесу" или
"Лучше платок на голове, чем соболья шапка в закладе"

ну и так далее. Какие-то полезные предметы сравнивать.

У меня было смутное подозрение, что синица - это жаргонное название какой-нибудь купюры, синего цвета. Но для журавля подобной интерпретации не слышала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синица - частый образ в русском (и белорусском)фольклоре. Она мала, незаметна,ничего из себя не представляет.Это подчёркивается в пословицах: Не велика птичка синичка; Синица не птица, а прапорщик не офицер; Синичку хоть в пшеничку, а толще не будет. При этом  в некоторых пословицах отмечается, что в случае необходимости и такая невзрачная птичка может пригодиться: Мала птичка, да ноготок остер; За морем и синица птица {там всё едят); Не величка синичка, да та же птичка. Из таких фольклорных ассоциаций и складывалась первая, исконно русская часть интернационального пословичного противопоставления. Журавль в небе-большое, лучшее, но труднодостижимое.

Вот здесь подробно:    http://www.poskart.ru/sinica-juravl.html

Comment: Да, спасибо, я тоже нашла этот сайт. Однако остается еще другой вопрос: почему нет аналогичных поговорок с "логичными" объектами, вроде приведенных мною. Но этот вопрос, конечно, риторический...

Answer (score 0):

> У меня было смутное подозрение, что синица - это жаргонное название какой-нибудь купюры, синего цвета.

Пятирублевая ассигнация первой половины XIX века.
http://monetaistarina.ru/product_890.html
Потом её заменили на другую, тоже синюю. В 60-х годах появился третий образец серо-синего цвета, но этого Гоголь уже знать не мог.

*Юрисконсульт отвечал на это изображеньем неверности всего земного и дал тоже искусно заметить, что журавль в небе ничего не значит, а нужно синицу в руку.

Нечего делать: нужно было дать синицу в руки. Скептическая холодность философа вдруг исчезла. Оказалось, что это был наидобродушнейший человек, наиразговорчивый и наиприятнейший в разговорах, не уступавший ловкостью оборотов самому Чичикову.*

Гоголь, "Мертвые души, 2 том". См. Комментарии к любому изданию.
Но, полагаю, это вторично. Гоголь просто скаламбурил на тему двух понятий "синица".

А вообще-то неоднократно обсуждалось на разного рода форумах.
Я только не понимаю, какой смысл Вы вкладываете в свое "почему"? Ну ладно, когда человек сторонний, но Вы-то должны понимать, что причинно-следственных связей тут не может быть? Так сложилось, что в ход пошла именно эта "версия" вполне понятной формулировки народной мудрости.

Comment: Н. В. Гоголь. Сорочинская ярмарка (1831-1832) Смотри же, не забывай: за пятнадцать! Вот тебе и синица в задаток! » «Ну, а если солжешь? »

Кроме синей ассигнации и "ручной" синицы была еще синица-поджигательница. Которая моря не зажгла, но своих пятнадцать минут славы получила!

Comment: Она-то с какого боку?

А про "Сорочинскую ярмарку" - там нет "синицы в руке". так-то можно найти и поболе.